# How to connect MySQL5 with VB6.0 by coding?

Tags: vb6, database-connection, connection-string

i want to connect my **Visual Basic 6.0**  Application with **MySQL5** database by coding not by DSN. what will be the connection string to connect them?
If anyone help me to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ConnStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" _
    & "SERVER=myserver;" _
    & "DATABASE=mydatabase;" _
    & "UID=myuserid;" _
    & "PWD=mypassword;" _
    & "OPTION=1"
```

Comment: @tchester- My code is : "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=acc_system;UID=root;PWD=abc123;OPTION=1".   it is giving runtime error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Comment: Check your ODBC control panel applet [Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)] to make sure that the MySQL 5.1 ODBC driver is installed. The DRIVER= statement should match the text that is displayed in your ODBC drivers list.